# Winsock closing socket

Tags: c++, networking, winsock, unreal-engine4

So I've been creating a winsock server/client in UE4. I can get the client to connect to the server however once the client sends the first message it seems to close the socket, preventing any further messages to be sent to the server. It also seems like the server is doing the same thing when sending data.

client

```
// Convert IP & port to standard lib
    const std::string IP = std::string(TCHAR_TO_UTF8((*GameInstance->GetIPAddress())));
    const std::string PORT = std::string(TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*GameInstance->GetPort()));
    // Set the version of WSA we are using
    auto Version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSAData WSData;
    struct addrinfo* Result = nullptr, * ptr = nullptr, hints;

    int iResult;                // Store Initializing results
    std::string message;        // Define a message to send to the server

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Starting Client"));

    // Initialize WinSock
   
    iResult = WSAStartup(Version, &WSData);         // Start winsock
    if(iResult != 0)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Failed to initialize winsock"));
        return ECreateConnectionFlag::WINSOCK_FAILED;
    }
    
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Initialized WinSock"));

    // Setup hints
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Connecting"));

    // Get the address details
    iResult = getaddrinfo(IP.c_str(), PORT.c_str(), &hints, &Result);
    if(iResult != 0)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Error getting address info from the server"));
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    // Connect the player
    for(ptr = Result; ptr != nullptr; ptr->ai_next)
    {
        GameInstance->SetPlayerSocket(socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol));
        if(GameInstance->GetLoggedInPlayer().PlayerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Failed to create socket"));
            WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }

        iResult = connect(GameInstance->GetLoggedInPlayer().PlayerSocket, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(GameInstance->GetLoggedInPlayer().PlayerSocket);
            GameInstance->SetPlayerSocket(INVALID_SOCKET);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(Result);               // Release Address information as it's no longer required

    // Ensure the socket is valid
    if(GameInstance->GetLoggedInPlayer().PlayerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Unable to connect to server..."));
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    

    // WE ARE CONNECTED

    /* CONNECT AND SEND USERNAME */
    FString SignInMessage = FString("Username-" + GameInstance->GetLoggedInPlayer().Username);
    std::string ConnectionMessage = std::string(TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*SignInMessage));
    iResult = send(GameInstance->GetLoggedInPlayer().PlayerSocket, ConnectionMessage.c_str(), (int)strlen(ConnectionMessage.c_str()), 0);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        int error = WSAGetLastError();
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Failed to send message: %d"), error);
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    while(bRunThread)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Receiving Data"));
        /* DISCONNECT FROM SERVER */
        const std::string msg = "Hello World";
        iResult = send(GameInstance->GetLoggedInPlayer().PlayerSocket, msg.c_str(), (int)strlen(msg.c_str()), 0);
        if(iResult <= 0)
        {
            int error = WSAGetLastError();
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Failed to send message: %d"), error);
            return 0;
        }
        FPlatformProcess::Sleep(1.0f);
    }

    /* DISCONNECT FROM SERVER */
    const std::string DisconnectMsg = "Disconnect";
    iResult = send(GameInstance->GetLoggedInPlayer().PlayerSocket, DisconnectMsg.c_str(), (int)strlen(DisconnectMsg.c_str()), 0);
    if(iResult <= 0)
    {
        int error = WSAGetLastError();
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Failed to send message: %d"), error);
        return 0;
    }

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Client Disconnected"));
    closesocket(GameInstance->GetLoggedInPlayer().PlayerSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

server

```
    WSAData wsa;                
    struct addrinfo hints;                          // Server Hint details
    struct addrinfo* server = NULL;                 // Address info of the server
    SOCKET serverSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;           // Server Listening Socket

    PlayerArray* Players = new PlayerArray();           // Reference to all the players in the server
    LobbyArray* Lobbies = new LobbyArray();             // Reference to all the lobbies in the server


    // Initialize the winsock library
    std::cout << "Initializing WinSock..." << std::endl;
    int WSA_Init = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if (WSA_Init != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error Initializing Winsock";
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Winsock Initialized" << std::endl;
    }

    // Setup Hints
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Setup the server
    std::cout << "Setting up Server" << std::endl;
    getaddrinfo(IP_ADDRESS, PORT, &hints, &server);

    // Create the listening socket
    std::cout << "Creating Listening socket" << std::endl;
    serverSocket = socket(server->ai_family, server->ai_socktype, server->ai_protocol);
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed creating listening socket" << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Created listen socket" << std::endl;
    }

    // Set the socket to be TCP
    setsockopt(serverSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &OPTION_VALUE, sizeof(int));

    // Bind the socket
    std::cout << "Binding Socket..." << std::endl;
    bind(serverSocket, server->ai_addr, (int)server->ai_addrlen);

    // Start the server
    std::cout << "Server has started & is listening..." << std::endl;
    listen(serverSocket, SOMAXCONN);

    while (true)
    {

        std::cout << "Players Connected: " << Players->Count() << std::endl;
        SOCKET Incoming = INVALID_SOCKET;               // Define a socket for anything incoming
        Incoming = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);        // Accept the incoming message from the socket

        // If the socket is not valid than continue through the loop
        if (Incoming == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid Socket" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Valid Socket" << std::endl;
        }
            

        char tempmsg[DFT_BUFLEN] = "";                  // Define a temp msg to store the message from the client
        int received = recv(Incoming, tempmsg, DFT_BUFLEN, 0);          // Receive a message from the client
        
        std::string convertedMessage = tempmsg;

        // Check that the received message is from a valid socket
        if (received != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            
            std::string message = tempmsg;              // Assing the temp message to a string to split
            if (convertedMessage == "Disconnect")
            {
                Players->RemovePlayer(Incoming);
                std::cout << "Player Disconnected..." << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << tempmsg << std::endl;                      // === DEBUG ===
                // Split the string
                char* next_split;
                char* split_string = strtok_s(tempmsg, "-", &next_split);
                std::string FirstMsg = split_string;
                if (FirstMsg == "Username")
                {
                    std::cout << next_split << " Has joined the server" << std::endl;           // Server message
                    // Get the player that we want to set the username to

                    // Create the player and add it to the server list
                    Player* NewPlayer = new Player();
                    Players->AddPlayer(NewPlayer);

                    NewPlayer->SetUsername(next_split);         // Set the usernames
                    continue;
                    

                }
                else if (split_string == "Lobby")
                {
                    if (next_split == "Create")
                    {
                        Lobby* NewLobby = Lobbies->CreateLobby();               // Create a new lobby
                        Player* SocketPlayer = Players->GetPlayerBySocket(Incoming);        // Get the player creating it by socket

                        // ensure that the player is valid, if so add the player to the lobby
                        // Otherwise send an error message to the console.
                        if (SocketPlayer != nullptr)            
                        {
                            NewLobby->AddPlayerToLobby(SocketPlayer);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            std::cerr << "Failed Locate player to add to lobby" << std::endl;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (next_split == "Destroy")
                    {
                        // TODO: Destroy Specific lobby
                    }

                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Error Reading Message" << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Socket Error when recieving message" << std::endl;
        }

        

    }

    // Clean up the server
    delete Players;
    delete Lobbies;
    closesocket(serverSocket);
    WSACleanup();



    return;
```

[Console output after disconnecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Lwi.png)

Comment: What does the server code look like? Where is `bRunThread` set? Also, the client is not deliminating its messages in any way, so the server has no way to know where one message ends and the next begins. What format is the server expecting the messages to use? Also, `strlen(string.c_str())` should be `string.size()` instead.

Comment: bRunThread is set in the constructor. I've posted the server code as well so you can see it parse

Comment: The server is not expecting any message boundaries at all. It assumes a 1:1 relationship between `send()` and `recv()`, and that is simply not the case. It also assumes `tempmsg` is null-terminated, which is not true, either. You MUST delimit your messages explicitly. Either: 1) send a message's length before its data, so the receiver can read the length first and then read how much data the length specifies; 2) send a unique terminator after each message, so the receiver can keep reading until that terminator is read. Examples of both techniques have been demonstrated MANY MANY times before.

Comment: You are only reading one message from each newly accepted client. Setting `TCP_NODELAY` on a server socket makes no sense whatsoever. You are ignoring the case when `recv()` returns zero. You are leaking the socket if you get any error.

Comment: I don't get any errors from the program, in fact the client says it sends the message, however the server doesn't receive it. What could I do differently so that it's receiving messages from all clients and not new client (I'm new to winsock)

Comment: Your revised code still doesn't handle `recv()` returning zero properly. It is not an error, and `WSAGetLastError()` therefore doesn't apply. You are still setting TCP_NODELAY on the listening socket. You are still leaking sockets. `(received != SOCKET_ERROR)` does not 'check that the received message is from a valid socket'. Too many basic errors here.

Comment: Okay so as I said can you please give me some suggestions rather than just telling me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Err, OK: (1) don''t handle `recv()` returning zero as an error: handle it as what the documentation says it is; (2) don't set TCP_NODELAY on a listening socket; (3) don't leak sockets when you get an error: close them; (4) fix your comment so it agrees with what the test really means, which is that you got an error on `recv()`; (4) loop reading messages per accepted socket until you get end of stream. Is this really such a mystery? NB Your title has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: NB 'TCP_NODELAY' does not 'set the socket to be TCP' either. Don't write misleading comments, even to yourself, and don't use features when you don't know what they're for. In this case the socket is already TCP by virtue of `hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;`.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a fundamental TCP mistake. TCP is a stream protocol., its only gurantees are

- the bytes you send will be received in the same order they were sent
- they will be received only once

*BUT* there are no 'messages' or 'records' in TCP. You can send a 100 byte message and the other end can receive

- one 100 byte message
- 25 4 byte messages
- 100 1 byte messages
- one 25, one 12, one 3, and one 60 (hope my math is correct)

So in the receive logic you must do this

```
  char buffer[1000]; // or whatever

  int length = ????;
  char* bptr = buffer;
  while(length > 0){

      int recvLen = recv(sock, bptr, length,0);
      if (recvLen < 1){
            // error - disconnect or other failure
           break;
      }
      bptr += recvLen;
      length -= recvLen;
  }
```

Ie keep pulling data till you have the whole message

*BUT* this means you need to know the messages length in advance. So either

- send a well known sized length first
- send fixed length messages

Or you can have a recognizable termination sequence- ie 10 byte of FF means end of message (see crlfcrlf at end of HTTP get for example)

The first option is the most robust (send length then data)

Comment: If you have a terminating sequence you also need an escape protocol for when the terminator appears as data.

Comment: The only issue is, the server isn't receiving any message at all, with how my server is know should it be receiving something? as you can see I've put a line to print the message we receive and it never gets hit

Comment: @Keegz510 i did not read the rest, I just point out that this code cannot work. Also the assignment of the input buffer to a string wont work because the input buffer is not zero terminated,

Comment: @Keegz510 can you paste into the question a full trace of a send receive seesion so I can see the flow (I mean your trace messages, not a network trace)

Comment: input buffer to a string works fine, If I try to compare the message as the input buffer it doesn't work, it only works as a string

Comment: @Keegz510 so string doesnt work then, you end up with "DisconnectFo!#%". CAn we see the trace please

Comment: But the issue i'm having is that it doesn't even receive the disconnect message, I'm printing the received message when I receive a message and nothing gets printed

Comment: @Keegz510 can you add the cout messages you are getting to the question please

Comment: I've uploaded an image of the console output, on client it should have connected but as you can see nothing is received by the server

Comment: @Keegz510 where is that 'players connected message'? right after 'listen'

Comment: @Keegz510 and all the other messages "valid socket'......

Comment: Valid socket shows when the first message is sent and same with players connected message, after that message though nothing else is received. someone mentioned that i may be only accepting messages from new clients, would that sound about right?

Comment: @Keegz510 please show the complete set of message for a session, pretty please

Comment: Your read loop is not correct. If `recvLen <= 0`, (1) You should not increment `bptr` or decrement `length`, and (2) you should exit the loop, reporting the `errno` or `WSAGetLastError()` if `recvLen == -1`.

Comment: @user207421 yes it needs to exit on 0 or -1 - done

Comment: It still needs to report the error on -1.

Comment: @user207421 indeed it does - hence the comment - but I do not know how to report an error in this abstracted code